# Upper bound for the number of representation numbers as the sum of two primes

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, goldbachs-conjecture

To prove strong goldbach conjecture one can use a lower bound of number of the representations of a number as the sum of two primes. If its greater than zero, than we have conjecture.

I wonder if there is an upper bound of this number of the  representations for a number $x$?

Edit: I have edited the question to tell the question in my head properly. I apologize for the people who answered this question.

Comment: Do you ask on a bound on how many ways there are to write $n$ as the sum of two primes? Francesco understood the question differently, I believe.

Comment: @DietrichBurde exactly.

Comment: Then you should edit. This is not clear from your text, as you see.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It would makes me really happy if you can create time to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

By a result of Helfgott, every even number $n  ≥ 4$ is the sum of at most four primes. This seems to be currently the best known result in this direction.

See the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) on the Goldbach's conjecture (in particular the section *Rigorous results*) and the references contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s define
$g2(n)=$ nbr of pairs of odd integers $p,q$ such that $p+q=2n$, $p$ and $q$ are prime, $p>1$, $q>1$
$g1(n)=$ nbr of pairs of odd integers $p,q$ such that $p+q=2n$, $p$ or $q$ is prime, $p>1$, $q>1$
$g0(n)=$ nbr of pairs of odd integers $p,q$ such that $p+q=2n$, $p$ and $q$ are not prime, $p>1$, $q>1$
Now consider the set of pairs of positive odd integers $p,q$ such that $p+q=2n$. 
p will go from: $$3 \to 2n-3$$
$q$ will go from: $$2n-3 \to 3$$ $p$ will be prime: $\pi(2n-3)-1$ times.
$q$ will be prime: $\pi(2n-3)-1$ times.
(the $-1$ is because we dont use  $2$)

So the set of pairs will contain: $2\pi(2n-3)-2 $ primes.
Therefore: $$2g2(n)+g1(n)=2\pi(2n-3)-2$$

Since $g1(n)$ cannot be $< 0$, an upper bound for $g2(n)$ is:
$$\frac{2\pi(2n-3)-2}{2}= \pi(2n-3)-1$$

Answer (score 0):

An obvious upper bound is $\pi(n/2)$.

EDIT: See [OEIS sequence A002375](https://oeis.org/A002375) and references there, in particular the first entry in the FORMULA section.

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a more powerful bound :)